# Can anyone identify this UK Victorian uniform?

Tags: identification, united-kingdom, uniform, victorian

I wondered if anyone could identify this uniform.
I know little about it other than it is a friend's ancestor.  It looks late 19th century to me.

[image: Beareded man in uniform standing next to table.]

Comment: [Jesse William Landon, photographer in Watford, 1873-1937.](http://www.hertfordshire-genealogy.co.uk/data/postcards/publisher-landon-watford.htm) Might help with narrowing it down.

Comment: I am guessing Grenadier Guards from the spacing of the buttons and the "slash" of the cuffs. Other foot guards regiments had different buttons; line infantry had different cuffs; and cavalry had different tunics entirely.

Comment: Thanks to both DevSolar and Julia for their helpful comments.
I'll pass the information on...